# Auth::attempt() only return false

Tags: laravel

I want to use manual authentication, but my code only return "false"

login code:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['username' => "myusername" , 'password' => '654321'])){
            return 'true';
        }else return 'false';
```

I registered users with this code:

```
$user = new User();
        $user->username = $request->username;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $user->api_token = $this->makeToken();
        $user->save();
```

i change key name of password for see query :

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'passsword' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `username` = mohammad and `passsword` = 654321 limit 1)"
```

Username and password not in quotation in query!

Comment: is the user credential correct?

Comment: @MilanMaharjan yes, I'm sure

Comment: You have  typo in password... you wrote passsword

Comment: @PatrikAlexits question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `extends Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` in User model

problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

First why you are using string as the credential for the username `myusername` and password `654321`?

Change your `myusername` and `654321` become :

```
if (Auth::attempt(['username' => request('username') , 'password' => request('password')])){
  return 'true';
}else return 'false';
```

Also make sure the `username` and `password` from the `request()` is the `name` of your post